# Date format is incorrect month is converted to year

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have a piece of code where the value is taken from the hidden input.

```
startDate = Convert.ToDateTime(((HtmlInputHidden)row.FindControl("hdmFromDate")).Value).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
endDate = Convert.ToDateTime(((HtmlInputHidden)row.FindControl("hdmToDate")).Value).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

The hidden input is nothing but a date value we get from SQL DB. So the users will get select the date from a drop down and add the start time and time in text box and save it. But when I checked the value that was saved is in a weird format.
So if the data from DB is 05-01-2017, after saving by users it will be saved as 2005-01-17. Does the user system date time format affects it. We can not ask the user to change their date and time format. Is there any way we can solve this.

Comment: When you say it's a "date value" you get from the SQL DB - what's the type of the field in SQL? If it's a text-based type, that's the first problem. Also note that you're calling `ToString` without specifying a `CultureInfo`, which means if they're in a culture that uses a non-Gregorian calendar by default, you'll have problems. Always specify the invariant culture for machine-to-machine conversions.

Comment: I would also point out the fact that nither c# nor sql server stores datetime display format, so if the date is saved with the proper data type in sql server, you should not mess with the string representation format of it.